# Power plans disappeared from system tray

Tags: windows-7, power

I just reinstalled Windows 7 Service Pack 1 in my HP laptop. After installing all drivers from HP, I installed HP Power Manager that comes with the factory installation and it broke something with the power managmement options in the system tray.

When I click the battery icon I don't see any plans to select. I have to click on `More power options` and then change the plan. The original list is empty:

[image: Empty power plans]

However the window that appears when clicking `More power options` actually shows the tree plans.

My question is: how can I "restore" the plans list in the system tray? Why are they hidden in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a command prompt and type the following command:

powercfg -restoredefaultscheme

I own a HP dv6 and the same happened to me ;)

Comment: I've reinstalled the laptop over time and never installd HP power management again, I guess your command would solve the problem then...